# checkbox limitation with ng-model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

so far I've only seen people used ng-model to bind the state of checkbox. How can I know which checkbox is checked with angularjs? for example I want to get the index of the checked checkedbox so that I can do something on the backend.

If it were in jquery / js I can use function to catch the state of the checkbox and send the index or etc info to be send back to database.

my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/dG9cwswiVzLdjEnpSNvu?p=preview

Comment: It looks like you have used properly. what you exactly want to do?

Comment: If checkbox is checked `item.done` will be `true`, Is it not good enough?

Comment: @JayShukla it's just some css, what if I want to run some function? for example grab the name of the checked checkbox? I need those data to be passed to the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-click`, like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kOTtbSHbw1kaGWmjqQbf?p=preview

Comment: lol this is so simple, thx.. I thought of passing param with ng-model which is stupid

Comment: can I pass multiple param? like ng-click="boxChecked({{groupId}},$index)"

Comment: Yes you can. I misunderstood your problem. :)

Comment: you don't need the {{ }}, so just try but `ng-click="boxChecked(groupId,$index)`

Comment: actually it's like this : item.groupId , that's why I put {{}}

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear about your problem but if you want label which associate with checkbox then  you should use `ng-init`.

```
<div ng-controller="main">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}" ng-model="item.done"><label for="{{$index}}" class="done-{{item.done}}" ng-init="item.text='Label for' + item.val">Label for {{item.val}}</label>
    </div>
    {{items}}
</div>
```

[See Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AW8yX3gC4ZIEgPOSKZmG?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for pointing out that Jay. how to pass multiple param like this  ng-click="boxChecked({{groupId}},$index)" ??